# Does a set of vectors which does not have an additive identity contain a zero vector?

Tags: vector-spaces

If a set of vectors $V$ fails to have an additive identity, does it make sense to say that the set of vectors does not contain a zero vector.

For example, let $V = \mathbb{R}^2$ be a set of vectors, with addition defined as:

$(u, v) + (x, y) = (u + x, 0)$

Clearly there is no additive identity:

$(u, v) + (0, a) = (u, 0) \ne (u, v)$, $a \in \mathbb{R}$

- Does this mean the set does not contain a zero vector?
- Does it make sense to talk about the zero vector outside of vector spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Yes. "The zero vector" is the name we give to the [additive] identity of a vector space.
- It doesn't make sense to talk about a zero "vector" outside of a vector space, definitionally. Vectors are elements of vector spaces.

Of course, $(0,0)$ is  still contained in $V$. But we wouldn't call it the zero vector of $V$. At most you could call it the zero vector of $\Bbb{R}^2$ (where the standard vector space structure is assumed).